# Leaflet vs Openlayers vs Geoserver for overlapping polygons application

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, polygon, leaflet

I have 3 layers of vector polygons(about 80 polygons - 1MB geojson each but I haven't simplified any yet) displaying school territories (kindergardens, primary and secondary education) and I want to produce a web map so that the user would know in which school his/her children "belong":
The plan is:

1. I enter my address
2. A **marker** on the address is created
3. A **radius** of 10 meters is created around the marker
4. The map **highlights** the polygons in which my address (marker with radius of 10 meters) lies **in** or are **near** (20 meters) to the point
5. I am **informed** about the name of each of the polygons my address(marker with radius of 10 meters) falls in.

The polygons may sometimes be more than 3 because some territories overlap another.

Can I implement all this tasks by using a **client-side** library (leaflet, openlayers)
or should I implement this project by using **server-side** geoserver?

Would I be able to create the radius around the marker point?
Would I be able to manage the overlapped polygons so that all of them are selected when a point lies within them and not just the top one?

Any ideas to help me start?

Comment: That is quite a few questions. Are you expecting to do the address seach using OpenLayers/Leaflet too? You can certainly do point in polygon and circle drawing quite easily in OpenLayers/Leaflet, but, obviously, you will need to have all the vectors loaded client side, so performance will depend on the size/complexity of your features, which you haven't specified. The multi-select of overlapping polygons requires you to write code (I have done this).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I will do my geocoding by using openlayers/leaflet and I know about point in polygon. But if I do the circle drawing as you suggest can I then use it to check which polygon it lies within? I thought that point in polygon works only for points and not for shapes(svg?).
By the way each layer contains about 80 polygons(about 1MB in geojson file but I haven't simplified  the polygons yet, so it would be much less).
So if you say that the multi-selection is doable I think I will go client-side. If the performance suffers I will create 3 different webpages for my 3 layers.

Comment: Just to update I did everything I wanted by using leaflet with cartodb's postgis capabilities to get the overlapping geometries.